# how do macro operator ## and ... work together in C

Tags: c, macros

I now trying to make a new flash driver for a specific chip which is not supported in openocd. Everything went well until I suddenly met the following code:

```c
/**
 * Command handlers may be defined with more parameters than the base
 * set provided by command.c.  This macro uses C99 magic to allow
 * defining all such derivative types using this macro.
 */

#define CALL_COMMAND_HANDLER(name, extra ...) \
      name(cmd, ## extra)
```

I looked up in **C Primer Plus** and I know **...** is for variadic macro and **##** is for gluing. However, I cannot understand how it comes to the code I mentioned before.

Comment: I believe this is a [`gnu` extension](https://gcc.gnu.org/onlinedocs/gcc/Variadic-Macros.html) that removes the preceding comma if `extra` is empty.

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.

Comment: @Community: The question is what does `cmd, ## extra` do in a macro replacement given that `, ## extra` is unlikely to form a valid preprocessor token in strictly conforming standard C.